# fading images simple slideshow javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I am extremely new to javascript and im trying to use fade out/fade in photo slide show and i am trying to use a code i have seen else where but it just doesnt seem to be working can someone have a look and just point out where i might be going wrong.

HTML

```
<div id="media" >
    <img src="test1.jpg" />
    <img src="test2.jpg"/>
    <img src="test3.jpg" />
</div>
```

css

```
#media
{
    border-style:groove;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:green;
    background-color:purple;
    height:34%;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-left:5%;
    float:left;
}
 #media img
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

script

```
     $('#media img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#media :first-child').fadeOut(4000)
                                 .next('img')
                         .fadeIn(10)
                         .end()
                         .appendTo('#media');
        }, 4000); // 4 seconds
    </script>
```

any help would be great.

thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: either my pictures dont change and/or fade or all three pictures appear instead of just one plus they also dont change.

Comment: It kind of sounds you don't linked the jQuery library correctly.. Where did you put the code to reference jQuery and how? Also, do you have the site online? It would be much easier to help if we got a bigger picture of what's going on. If not, try putting relevant code in a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) and link to it.

Comment: you were right! i was missing the .js on the query library links! GOD so stupid! thank you for that didnt even consider that thought it was related to my use of id instead of class!! THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could accomplish this. Maybe something like:

```
$(function() {
    var images = $(".images img").hide();
    var current = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var next = ((current + 1) % images.length);
        images.eq(current).fadeOut();
        images.eq(next).fadeIn();
        current = next;
    });
});
```

However, in your CSS page you'd also want to add:

```
.images
{
    position: relative;
}
.images img
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This is great if you want some to fade into others?

Check out this page, has some other concepts very similar using jQuery: http://www.geeksucks.com/toolbox/23-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.htm

Comment: this also worked just a question why would you use .image (eg a class) instead of #image (eg an id)?